# Ordered fields properly containing $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading [this](http://www.math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf) supplementary to Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, and I came across 'Properties of ordered fields properly containing $\Bbb R$' (on page 8). Please check if I have understood correctly:

> Suppose $\Bbb F$ is  an ordered field properly containing $\Bbb R$, then for every $x\in \Bbb R$, there are infinitely many 'immediate successors' $\alpha_1,\alpha _2,\dots \in\Bbb F-\Bbb R$ such that $\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\dots$ and infinitely many 'immediate predecessors' $\beta_1,\beta _2,\dots \in\Bbb F-\Bbb R$ such that $\beta_1<\beta_2<\dots$ .

Here, I use this definition:

Let $a\in \Bbb R$ and $\gamma\in \Bbb F$ and $a<\gamma$. If set $\{z\in \Bbb R\ : a<z<\gamma\}$ is empty, then we say that $\gamma$ is *immediate successor* of $a$.

> Also, Please recommend some reading about  ordered fields properly containing $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Strange notion. The term "immediate successor" is used for something else in order theory. Anyway, yes, if $\mathbb F$ is an ordered field properly containing $\mathbb R$, then it contains infinitesimal elements and infinite elements, infinitely many of each and so, yes, given any point in $\mathbb R$ there is a "cloud" of new elements infinitely close to it both from above and from below and in particular this cloud contains such increasing (and similarly, decreasing) sequences as you indicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1). Preliminary. Let $F,G$ be sub-fields of $\Bbb R$ which are isomorphic as fields.

Theorem: If $\sqrt x\;\in F$ whenever $0<x\in F$ then the only field-isomorphism $h:F\to G$ is $id_F$ and $F=G.$

Proof: Let $h:F\to G$ be a field-isomorphism. If $x,y\in F$ with $x>y$ then $$0\ne h(x-y)=h((\sqrt {x-y}\;)^2)=(h(\sqrt {x-y}\;))^2$$ so $h(x)>h(y).$ So $h$ preserves order. Since $\Bbb Q\subset F$ and $h|_{\Bbb Q}=id_{\Bbb Q}$ we have $$\forall x\in F\;\forall q\in \Bbb Q\;(q<x\iff q=h(q)<h(x)\;).$$ So for $x\in F$ we have $\{q\in \Bbb Q: q<x\}=\{q\in \Bbb Q:q<h(x)\},$ which implies $x=h(x).$

Corollary: If $\Bbb R$ is a proper sub-field of an ordered field $H$ then $H$ is not field-isomorphic to $\Bbb R.$

Proof: If not,  let $g:H\to \Bbb R$ be a field-isomorphism. Applying the above theorem with $F=g(\Bbb R)$ and $G=\Bbb R=g(H)$ we have $F=G.$ That is, $g(\Bbb R)=g(H),$ so $\Bbb R=g^{-1}(g(\Bbb R))=g^{-1}(g(H))=H.$

(2). Main argument. Let $\Bbb R$ be a proper sub-field of the ordered field $H$ where the order on $\Bbb R$ is inherited from the order on $H.$  Then $H$ is not order-complete because any complete ordered field is field-isomorphic to $\Bbb R,$ but by the corollary above, $H$ is not field-isomorphic to $\Bbb R.$

So let $\phi\ne S\subset H$ where $S$ has an upper bound but lub $S$ does not exist.

(i). If no $x\in \Bbb R$ is an upper bound for $S,$ let $t$ be any upper bound for $S.$ Then $0<1/t<x$ for every $x\in \Bbb R^+$.

(ii). If some $r\in \Bbb R$ is an upper bound for $S$ then let $r_0$ be the glb in $\Bbb R$ ($not$ the glb in $H$) of the set of real-number upper bounds for $S.$ We split now to two sub-cases:

Case (ii-a).... If there exists $s\in S$ with $s>r_0$ then $s\not \in \Bbb R$ (Otherwise the def'n of $r_0$ implies $r_0\geq s$, but we have $r_0<s$). So $s-r_0>0.$

Now $0<s-r_0<x$ for every $x\in \Bbb R^+.$ Because if $x\in \Bbb R$ and $0< x\leq s-r_0$ then  $r_0<x+r_0\leq s ,$ but then any real number $r$ that is an upper bound for $S$ would satisfy $r\geq x+r_0\in \Bbb R,$ contrary to the def'n of $r_0.$

Case (ii-b).... If $s\leq r_0 $ for every $s\in S$ then  $r_0$ is an upper bound for $S$ but $r_0\ne$  \lub $S$. So let $t$ be an upper bound for $S$ with $t<r_0.$ Now $0<r_0-t<x$ for every $x\in \Bbb R^+.$ Because if  $x\in \Bbb R$ and  $0<x\leq r_0-t$ then $r_0>r_0-x\geq t,$ but then the  real number $r_0-x$ is an upper bound for S, and is less than $r_0,$ contrary to the def'n of $r_0.$

Conclusion: In each of (i), (ii-a), and (ii-b) we obtain some $y\in H^+$ such that $\forall x\in \Bbb R^+\;(y<x).$ So for any $x\in \Bbb R$  we have, for every $n\in \Bbb N$,    $$x-(n+1)y^2<x-ny^2 <x<ny^2<(n+1)y^2$$  $$\text { and }\quad \Bbb R\cap (x-ny^2,x+ny^2)=\phi.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I will read this thoroughly.

Comment: I thought it might be too long. BTW there are easy ways to construct examples of a field H of my answer.

Comment: Sir, I am obliged.